# Storing Arrays in Database

Tags: php

Ok, I'm trying to read a csv file that the user uploads. It will have one column and many rows. Each row will have a URL in it. I have it uploaded and have the data sorted but I can't figure out how to properly extract that data and store it into the database.

**EDIT**

When I do a `var_dump($csv)` I get the following:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'http://example.com' (length=18)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'http://example2.com' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'http://example3.com' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'http://example4.com' (length=19)
  4 => boolean false
```

How can I store each of these URLs as a new record in a table?

**EDIT #2**

When using this code:

```
   foreach($csv as $v) {
      if($con->query("INSERT INTO table_name (url) VALUES('$v')")) {
      }
      else{
        // connection failure
      }
    }
```

I get the following error:

**Notice: Array to string conversion in**

That is referring to my if statement above. I get 4 notices (which it should be storing 4 records with the file I'm working with so that makes sense)

It also stores 5 records to the database. The first 4 have "Array" in the url column and the last one is totally blank.

Comment: Why do you need to sort it? The database doesn't care what order you insert them.

Comment: Maybe sort was the wrong word. I just need to store it in any order.

Comment: It looks to me like your file isn't really a CSV. There's just one element on each line, nothing separated by commas.

Comment: Do you need the array intact? Or do you need the links stored in their seperate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mysqli`, first make a secure page like:

**connect.php**

```
<?php  // change the Strings in quotes below
function db(){
  return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
}
?>
```

**othepage.php**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; $db = db(); $csv = readCSV($csvFile);
foreach($csv as $a){
  foreach($a as $v){
    if($db->query("INSERT `url_table_name` (`url_column_name`) VALUES('$v')"){
    }
    else{
      // connection failure
    }
  }
}
$db->close();
?>
```

Comment: Array to String conversion error. It stored 5 records in the database. The first four all say "Array" in the url field and the 5th is blank.

Comment: I've amended my question using your code and the error I get.

Comment: Assuming the results are in Arrays and they all have a series of useful values, I ran another loop. Why don't you `print_r()` the old code `$v` and take a look.

Comment: Thanks a ton @PHPglue This seems to work exactly how I was needing it. I accepted the answer but could you please correct the syntax error above. You are missing a closing ) at the end of the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using PDO (it's similar with mysqli, but you use `bind_param` instead of `bindParam`):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName (url) VALUES (:url)");
$stmt->bindParam(':url', $url);
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    $url = $row[0];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I assume `id` is an auto-increment field, so leaving it out of the `INSERT` will assign it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for();` and a `foreach();` loop to loop through the arrays and get the data. Then within the loop query the database.

```
<?php
$arr = [
    0 => [
        0 => "http://example.com"
    ],

    1 => [
        0 => "http://example2.com"
    ]
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    foreach ($arr[$i] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**Output**

`0 => http://example.com
0 => http://example2.com`

Comment: It is saying that the foreach line provides an invalid argument.

Comment: What did you provide in your `foreach` loop?

Comment: What should I provide? I realize what a retarded question this is. I'm fairly new so bare with me. Where should $key and $value get their value from? The only thing I changed was the $arr variable. Using the code I have above, I changed that variable name to $csv.

Comment: That's probably where the invalid argument comes in. It's hard for me to explain this all too as I don't know what the heck I'm doing apparently.

Comment: `$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($csv);
  echo '</pre>'; 

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($csv); $i++) {
      foreach ($csv[$i] as $key => $value) {
          echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
      }
  }`

Comment: And I've got the output just like your output above, it just shows a warning too about the foreach line being an invalid argument.

Comment: Remove the `[$i]` part and the `for` loop around the `foreach` loop, see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91893/discussion-between-jds-and-script47).

Comment: Shows an "array to string" conversion error when I remove [$i] in that statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the array intact without sorting through the array and saving each element into the database in it's own row. Your best solution would be:

```
$Array = array(
    0 => array ("http://www.example.com"),
    1 => array ("http://www.example2.com"),
    2 => array ("http://www.example3.com")  
);

echo serialize($Array);
```

Which would output:

> a:3:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:22:"http://www.example.com";}i:1;a:1:{i:0;s:23:"http://www.example2.com";}i:2;a:1:{i:0;s:23:"http://www.example3.com";}}

This string can be saved into a single row in the database and retrieved by a simple select query and performing:

```
 $Unser = unserialize($unserializedArray);
```

so running:

```
$Array = array(
    0 => array ("http://www.example.com"),
    1 => array ("http://www.example2.com"),
    2 => array ("http://www.example3.com")  
);

$Ser = serialize($Array);

print_r(unserialize($Ser));
```

will output:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => http://www.example.com ) [1] => Array (
>   [0] => http://www.example2.com ) [2] => Array ( [0] =>
>   http://www.example3.com ) )